# What are the benefits of encapsulation?

Tags: java, encapsulation

I understand that there a lot of great answers on SO on this subject but I want to know is the benefits of **purely** encapsulation.

But the answers out there always introduce the benefits of **information hiding** instead such as

> 1)Not breaking the users of the class
>
> 2)Allows validation of input via the setter methods
>
> 3)Makes debugging easier since we just have to look at the
> behaviour(ie method calls) of the class to see what went wrong

But none of this talks **strictly** about encapsulation.

---

This is what I think  encapsulation is

-Combining related state and behaviour in 1 name(in context of OOP, that's a class)

Based on this definition, the only benefits I can think of i is:

> 1. Supports black-box behaviour for reusability
>
> 2. This may seem kind of forced but I couldn't think of any-Gives a "out of sight, out of mind" mindset

Comment: Good news! "Information hiding" is another way to say "encapsulation". A "purely encapsulated" object hides all of it's internal state, because a caller should not need to know about it. When you call the fire department, do you need to first ask for a list of all trucks they have then a list of which people are available and then try and roster your own truck? Or do you just tell them your house is on fire and let them sort it out?

Comment: Oh, are you then saying encapsulation is just a technique to apply information-hiding? Is that why people talking about information-hiding when someone asks about encapsulation since they seem to be used interchangeably?

Comment: Pretty much. It's about separating concerns. The caller should not need to: list available trucks, list available firefighters, assign the correct # of people to the truck, and then give the driver directions to the location of the fire. Those operations should be encapsulated within the abstraction that is a `FireDepartment`. Further, my girlfriend should not be able to just call the `FireDepartment` and get a list of "hot" firefighters. She's got to go there in person. Or start a fire. Excuse me.

Comment: To add to Elliot's statements, encapsulation's entire purpose is information-hiding, I don't see any other reason to use it. It is used both to make sure that only those who need to be able to access something directly have the ability, thus ensuring that all external access is maintained as expected. That can include input-validation when setting or just a complex code to get a specific field, requiring a delicate approach that the developer doesn't trust (or doesn't want to force) others to achieve. By the way, @ElliottFrisch you may want to keep an eye out for flammable objects...